# MS SQL I try to return the number of Loc_id per hour per day

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

> in MS SQL I try to return the number of Loc_id per hour per day.
>
> As long as I have 1 line per Loc_id in the DB it works fine.
>
> Unfortunately some Loc_id have several lines returning wrong results.
>
> The Total is correct, but not the result per hour.
>
> I tried with a multiple nested query but it doesn't work if one of the fields returns zero (with is the case)
>
> I stripped the query down to 3 hour for Stackoverflow ;-)

```
SELECT 
    'Date ' = (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()-1, 121)), 
    'Area ' = case when loc_m =67 then 'AMBIENT' when loc_m =77 then 'COLD' else 'NARCOTIC' end ,

    ' 12H ' = sum(case when substring(insert_time,12,2) = '12' And loc_id <> 'NOREAD____' then 1 else 0 end),
    ' 13H ' = sum(case when substring(insert_time,12,2) = '13' And loc_id <> 'NOREAD____' then 1 else 0 end), 
    ' 14H ' = sum(case when substring(insert_time,12,2) = '14' And loc_id <> 'NOREAD____' then 1 else 0 end), 

    ' Total ' = count(*)

FROM history_inventory

    WHERE    (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),insert_time, 121)) = (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE()-1, 121))
    AND hist_inv_type = 2 
    AND action = 'ADD ' 
    AND loc_m in ('67','77','96') 
    GROUP BY loc_m
```

> RESULT

```
1. Date_________Area______12H_____13H_____14H_____Total 
2. 2018-08-15___AMBIENT___179_____277_____285_____1878 
3. 2018-08-15___COLD_______61_____149_______0_____336
4. 2018-08-15___NARCOTIC____0______33______12______74
```

-

Comment: Please provide the table definition (CREATE TABLE) and some sample data showing your problem and the results you want to see.  Also, think about cleaning up your query:  Don't use old-style aliasing (e.g. 'date' = ...) but rather <expression> as <alias> and don't put leading/trailing blanks in column names.  Also, you don't need to add trailing blanks in conditions.  It just looks messy that way.

Comment: CREATE TABLE : 

> action (char(4), null)
       
> loc_m (int, null)
 
> loc_id (char(4), null)

> product (char(20), null)
      
> batch  (char(40), null)
      
>change  (float, null)
      
>insert_time -- (PK, char(26), not null)
  
> FROM history_inventory

Comment: i think the column alias style `=` vs `as` is very subjective. I don't see any significant advantage of using `as` instead of `=`

Comment: Sample data will go a long way toward helping us help you here. See this article for suggestions on how to edit your question. [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Comment: Can I upload the sample data in file?